# How could i change the color of a link while hover and active link should be the background color (alternation)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want the result of reverse coloring of font and background while hover and after clicking the link, but I am stuck with the hover link color might coincide with the background color, I could not get the reversibility.

```
<script>
    $('#setup_list li a').click(function(){
        var link_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#setup_list li a').css('background-color','#3498DB');
        $('#setup_list > li > a').removeClass('link_activate');
        $(this).addClass('link_activate');
        $(this).css('background-color','#fff');
   });
</script>
```

I have one item that has a hover method attached to it, and when you hover it displays another div on top of it... unfortunately once the upper div displays it redoes the actions (since i added the same class for it to actually stick around)

```
li {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:20px 0;
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.navbar-sidebar li a {
    color:#fff;
    border:1px #3498DB solid;
  padding:5px;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.navbar-sidebar li a:hover {
    color:#3498DB;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:1px #3498DB solid;
}

.link_activate {
    color:#3498DB;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:1px #3498DB solid;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e13msz7f/1/

Comment: Please take the time to format your questions properly. It make it much easier to read, and more likely you'll get quick and accurate help

Comment: Removed duplication and what appeared to be a second question asked inside the first

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code i made that you can use to switch between color and background color.

```js
$("li").on("mouseover", function() {
  $link = $(this).css("color");
  $backgoundColor = $(this).css("background-color");
  $(this).css("color", $backgoundColor);
  $(this).css("background-color", $link);
}).on("mouseout", function() {
   $link = $(this).css("color");
  $backgoundColor = $(this).css("background-color");
  $(this).css("color", $backgoundColor);
  $(this).css("background-color", $link);
});
```

```css
li
{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:20px 0;
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.navbar-sidebar li a
{
 color:#fff;
 border:1px #3498DB solid;
  padding:5px;
  background-color: #3498DB;
}

.navbar-sidebar li a:hover
{
 color:#3498DB;
 outline: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:1px #3498DB solid;
}

.link_activate
{
 color:#3498DB;
 outline: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:1px #3498DB solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="setup_list" class="nav navbar-sidebar">
    
    <li><a href="">Cus</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Com</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Temp</a></li>
</ul>
```